# Using props if/else statement in react

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, react-props

I'm using props to return a language from an api call. Currently the props is showing 'en' as it is from the api, however I want to use a if statement to show `if ({books.language}==='en'){
return 'English')

```
    const BookCard = () => {
  const { results, addBooktoArray, addLastReadBook } = useContext(BookContext);

  return (
    <>
      {results.map((book) => (
        <Grid key={book.id} id={book.id}>
          <Card sx={{ width: 350, height: 700 }}>
            {/* Cover */}
            <CardMedia
              component="img"
              alt={book.title}
              height="75%"
              image={`https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/${book.id}/pg${book.id}.cover.medium.jpg`}
            />

            <CardContent>
              {/* Booktitle */}
              <Typography
                variant="h5"
                noWrap
                sx={{
                  p: 1,
                  fontWeight: 600,
                  color: "inherit",
                  textDecoration: "none",
                }}
              >
                {book.title}
              </Typography>
              {/* Author */}
              <Typography
                variant="subtitle1"
                noWrap
                sx={{
                  p: 1,
                  color: "inherit",
                  textDecoration: "none",
                }}
              >
                by {book.authors[0] ? book.authors[0].name : "Unknown Author"}
              </Typography>
              <CardActions>
                <BookModal 
                title={book.title}
                author={book.authors[0].name}
                subjects={book.subjects}
                {(()=> {
                  if (book.language === "en") {
                    return ('English')
                  }
                  else {
                    return(book.language)
                  }
                })()}
                language={book.languages}
                description= {book.title}
                />
                <Link
                  to={`/Reader/${book.id}`}
                  onClick={(e) => createBook(book)}
                >
                  <Button size="medium" onClick={addLastReadBook}>
                    READ
                  </Button>
                </Link>
                <Tooltip title="Add to Bookshelf">
                  <IconButton onClick={addBooktoArray}>
                    <BookmarkAddIcon />
                  </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
              </CardActions>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default BookCard;
```

I've also tried writing the if/else statement as this.state.language above the return but it crashes my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the IIFE there so that it's part of a prop (or a child). If you want the `English` string to replace the `language` prop, for example, then you'd need to move the IIFE after `language={`, like:

```
<BookModal 
    title={book.title}
    author={book.authors[0].name}
    subjects={book.subjects}
    language={(() => {
        if (book.language === "en") {
            return ('English')
        } else {
            return book.language;
        }
    })()}
    description={book.title}
/>
```

A more concise approach would be

```
language={book.language === 'en' ? 'English' : book.language}
```

Or, if you want to change multiple language strings, use an object.

```
const langsByAbbreviation = {
  en: 'English',
  es: 'Español',
};

// ...

language={langsByAbbreviation[book.language] ?? book.language}
```